# Import text value with included spacers

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The important elements are:

```
<td scope="col" class="leftPad">
  <a href="http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/pt/betting/e/21159134/Forge+v+Cavalry.html">
    <span id="21159134_mkt_namespace">Forge &nbsp; v &nbsp;&nbsp;Cavalry</span></a>
```

I would like to collect the value:

```
Forge &nbsp; v &nbsp;&nbsp;Cavalry
```

But when I try to import the value it returns it's:

```
Forge   v   Cavalry
```

Is there any way to import the value with the spacers `&nbsp;`?

My current formula is:

```
=IMPORTXML(
           "http://sports.williamhill.com/bet/pt/betlive/9",
           "//tr[@class='rowLive']//td[@scope='col']//a//span/text()"
          )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA(A1)), 
 "where Col1 starts with '<a href=' 
    and Col1 contains '&nbsp'", 0),
 "namespace"">(.+)<\/span"))
```

[image]

or:

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(IMPORTXML(A1, 
 "//tr[@class='rowLive']//td[@scope='col']//a//span/text()"),
 "  v   ",  "&nbsp; v &nbsp;&nbsp;"))
```

[image]